# New to coding, code to update year of copyright on website glitch?

Tags: javascript

For some reason the code I am using with the software Openelement is causing an extra addition to the code

My cheat currently is to have a blank image cover the mistake at the bottom of the footer lol

The code I used is

```
    javascript:<p class="copyright"> company name ltd. © <script>var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();document.write(currentYear);</script>, All Rights Reserved.</p>
```

The end result i would like is:

Home - About - Services - Contact -
company name ltd. © 2019, All Rights Reserved.

but i keep getting:

Home - About - Services - Contact -
company name ltd. © 2019, All Rights Reserved.
">

Comment: Please show the part where this code is included. The information you provide is very sparse, making it harder to answer the question.

Comment: Apologies, first post, just noticed the code didn't load due to not adding code block, see edit for code

Comment: Your existing code appears to [work correctly](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwsmjx2b/).  If you can include more of the surrounding context in the question we might be better able to track down where the extra `">` is coming from; it's not caused by the code in the question.

Comment: i just inspected the code on chrome and it has "&gt;&nbsp; &nbsp; included for some reason, and i think this is where is it tripping up, any idea what this could be? I can add code blocks on the openelement software rather than have the code added through a text box, especially as the code is ok itself, but if anyone has any ideas please let me know, thanks for the help thus far.

Answer (score 0):

`var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();document.write(currentYear);` is script code. Try like following:

```js
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var copyRight = "company name ltd. © " + currentYear + ", All Rights Reserved.";
document.getElementById("copyRight").innerHTML = copyRight;
```

```html
<p id="copyRight"></p>
```

Your code is also working fine let's have a look here:

```html
<p class="copyright"> company name ltd. © <script>var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();document.write(currentYear);</script>, All Rights Reserved.</p>
```